# Mule 4 Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, mulesoft, mule4

Is there any way to call mule "flow" instance using groovy ? like When I use the groovy script and it will call the another flow, that means ( calls the another flow -- > sets the variable value and get back with the results). = Expected Behaviour.

### Requirement :

Like, Mule Flow **A** is running independently and keep on incrementing variable value.

Mule flow **B** wants to access the Flow **A** variable (Incremental value) ( only variable ) using groovy or python Script.

Note: Script should not execute flow **A** for getting variable value.

Is there method like to get instance of variable in groovy ? like

flow=registry.lookupByName('A-flow').getInstance(VariableName) ?

// Need to get only variable value.

### Groovy Script to call a Mule flow:

```
 import org.mule.runtime.api.message.Message;
 import org.mule.runtime.core.api.event.CoreEvent;
 import org.mule.runtime.core.api.event.EventContextFactory;
 flow=registry.lookupByName('A-flow').grep();
 msg = Message.builder().value(payload).build();
 event =CoreEvent.builder(EventContextFactory.create(flow, org.mule.runtime.dsl.api.component.config.
    DefaultComponentLocation.fromSingleComponent("add-location"))).message(msg).build();
 result =flow.process(event);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "static flow"? You said that the flow A is already running. which means it is already "started", then why do you not want the script to "start" the flow?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "MuleSoft flow". The right name would be a Mule flow.

Comment: @HarshankBansal -1) I have created one mule flow A with in the mule project having one variable and value set to 100.  2) Created one more flow (new configuration.xml) named it as B. Would like to access flow A variable using groovy or any other script.

Comment: @aled Yes Mule flow only.

Comment: @HarshankBansal I dont want to start the flow . I just want to access the private flow  variable using script.

Answer (score 1):

> Mule flow B wants to access the Flow A variable with out deploying or
> starting the flow A (as it is running independently ) using groovy or
> python Script.

Variables live inside a [Mule Event](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/about-mule-event), which is really what contains the status of an execution triggered from a flow. However even if you get a list of all active events you may not know which one is the one you are interested. It is also a bad practice trying to use Mule internals inside an application.

Instead you should share the value of the variable you are interested using a standard method for Mule, like an object store, a queue or database. It really depends on what you are trying to do and the design of your application what is the method that will fit best.